# Firefox add on extension main.js (main.html)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way in Firefox addon API we could have our background page be a HTML file instead of a JS file ?

This is available in both Safari and Chrome and I was wondering if there was a way to do it in Firefox addon API.

Right now I am using a page-worker API and I pass objects around. But it would be really convenient if we could just have the main.js be a main.html or something.

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.
You can use the module `sdk/addon/window` to access to a window associated to your add-on, but the `main.js` is a commonjs module, and is running in a sandboxed environment – like nodejs – without a DOM.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured as well. Thanks !